# setState takes more time when called from a timer

Tags: reactjs

This is a SSCCE from a hard to explain performance problem I observed.

We have a very simply React app whose state is a single counter.
The user presses a button to increment the counter **or** presses another button to keep incrementing the counter continuously. That's it.

We measure the time `setState` takes using `performance.now`.

Turns out `setState` takes an order of magnitude more time when called from the timer.

Typical values in my system for the manual clicking case:

```
cost was: 0.03999999999359716
cost was: 0.020000000004074536
cost was: 0.02500000000873115
```

Values for the continuous increment case:

```
cost was: 1.2200000000011642
cost was: 1.0449999999982538
cost was: 3.084999999991851
```

Code is:

```
const React = require('react');
var TimerMixin = require('react-timer-mixin');

const App = React.createClass({
    mixins: [TimerMixin],
    getInitialState: function() {
        return {    counter: 0, continuous: false };
    }
    , increment() {
        const t0 = performance.now();
        this.setState({counter: this.state.counter+1});
        const t1 = performance.now();
        console.log(`cost was: ${t1-t0}`);
    }
    , toggleContinuousIncrement() {
        this.setState({continuous: !this.state.continuous}, ()=>{
            if (this.state.continuous)
                this.continuousIncrement();
        });
    }
    , continuousIncrement: function() {
        if (this.state.continuous) {
            this.increment();
            this.setTimeout(this.continuousIncrement, 30);
        }
    }

    , render: function() {
        const toggleContinuousIncrement = this.state.continuous
                                           ?"stop continuous increment"
                                           :"start continuous increment";
        return (
                <div>
                    <div>
                        {this.state.counter}
                    </div>
                    <button onClick={this.increment}>increment counter</button>
                    <button onClick={this.toggleContinuousIncrement}>{toggleContinuousIncrement}</button>
                </div>
        );
    }


});

export default App;
```

Comment: Not sure what you are asking here, setState has no guarantees as documented in https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#setstate i.e. it can take a different code path, Maybe profile  to see what set state does instead? Quoting the page `There is no guarantee of synchronous operation of calls to setState and calls may be batched for performance gains`. Can this be a synchronous vs batched update that you're seeing?

Comment: for `setState` to be able to distinguish the two cases it would have to examine the stack in which it gets called. So that if it's called from an event handler it takes one path whereas if it's called from a timer it takes another. I would have thought that to be an unusual thing for a function to do.

Comment: I guess state updates in onClick and other event handlers is easily detected (No need to inspect stack). Also I wouldn't want my eventhandler to take too long, i.e. in a mouseMove. I would assume these could be scheduled with requestAnmiationFrame.